# SQL how can I have sql return one row instead of multiple per distinct ID?

Tags: sql

According to my coworker, We are using IBM DB2

Having real hard time trying to make my sql return one row per ID.  Asked around at work but no girl here are good with SQL...  I can do some sql but am no SQL expert.

To explain it better, I set up the example below

Here is the TABLE and its data

```
ID  DATE        CODE  PERCENT
01  2016-08-21  1111  52
01  2016-09-06  1111  60
01  2016-10-06  1112  38
02  2016-05-01  6666  50
02  2016-10-01  1111  50
```

I want one record returned per each ID with earliest DATE.
so I wrote below SQL

```
SELECT ID, MIN(DATE) 
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE >= '2016-01-01' AND  DATE <= '2017-11-01'
AND   CODE = 1111
GROUP BY ID
```

that worked fine.  I would get

```
01 2016-08-21
02 2016-10-01
```

I soon realized that I also need PERCENT column.

```
SELECT ID, MIN(DATE), PERCENT
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE >= '2016-01-01' AND  DATE <= '2017-11-01'
AND   CODE = 1111
GROUP BY ID, PERCENT
```

but now, I'm getting the multiple rows for ID 01 which is wrong...

```
01  2016-08-21  1111  52
01  2016-09-06  1111  60
02  2016-10-01  1111  50
```

Can somebody help me fix this SQL or point me to the right direction so that I can have one row per ID like below?

```
01  2016-08-21  1111  52
02  2016-10-01  1111  50
```

Comment: Is this in MS SQL Server?

Comment: Which dbms???????????  SQL is just a language.  Implementation is different from one dbms to another.

Comment: Alison, it is very important to know what database type you are using (e.g. MySQL Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server ...) because the solution will depend on what the database supports. "SQL" isn't enough detail  by itself.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY ID will do the necessary, no need to GROUP BY percent. A new row will be added if you GROUP BY percent since it has a different value.

```
SELECT ID, MIN(DATE), code, percent
FROM table
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-11-01'
AND   CODE = 1111
GROUP BY ID;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will break in almost all of dbms.

Answer (score 1):

**IF** you database supports `row_number() over()` then using that function is an excellent way of determining which rows are "the earliest" like this:

```
select *
from (
       select *
          , row_number() over(partition by ID, CODE order by DATE ASC) as is_oldest
       from YOURTABLE
       where DATE >= '2016-01-01' AND  DATE <= '2017-11-01'
       and CODE = 1111
     ) d
where is_oldest = 1
```

The significant advantage of this is it provides access to the whole row associated with "the oldest" without needing a join.

Note the flexibility of this approach too, it can easily be extended e.g.

```
select *
from (
       select *
          , row_number() over(partition by ID, CODE order by date ASC) as is_oldest
          , row_number() over(partition by ID, CODE order by date DESC) as is_recent
       from your_table
       WHERE DATE >= '2016-01-01' AND  DATE <= '2017-11-01'
       AND   CODE = 1111
     ) d
where is_oldest = 1
or is_recent = 1
```

All one has to do to get "the most recent" is change the order from ASCending to DESCending.

NB: MySQL prior to v8 does not support "window functions such as row_number, but it is planned at v8 onward. Many other databases do support this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Earliest.ID,
    Earliest.Date,
    TABLE.PERCENT
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        MIN(DATE)
    FROM
        TABLE
    WHERE 
        DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND  '2017-11-01'
        AND CODE = 1111
    GROUP BY ID
) AS Earliest
INNER JOIN TABLE ON Earliest.ID = Table.ID
```

To explain why your adjusted query is returning multiple records: The percent column has different data, and so when you group by it, it will add a new record for every change on that.

In this answer you get the percent from the underlying table by joining to the summarised results.

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server, you can use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` along with an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID, DATE, PERCENT
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE >= '2016-01-01' AND  DATE <= '2017-11-01'
AND  CODE = 1111
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE ASC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not group by PERCENT, just group by ID. Add code in the select statement.

```
select id, min(date), code, percent
from tablename
where date between '2016-01-01' AND  '2017-11-01'
and   code = 1111
group by id;
```

Comment: this code is not ANSI SQL conformant but will run on Sybase ASE and maybe MySQL. they accept select without group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

The reason PERCENT defeats the group by is because PERCENT is different between rows and you are *removing duplicates* with GROUP BY.  PERCENT makes the row different...  You can instead subquery to re-acquire the row from the table that has the same ID and MIN(DATE)

```
SELECT dT.ID
      ,dT.DATE
      ,(SELECT T.PERCENT
          FROM TABLE T
         WHERE T.ID = dT.ID AND T.DATE = dT.DATE
       ) AS Percent
  FROM (
         SELECT ID, MIN(DATE) AS DATE
           FROM TABLE
          WHERE DATE >= '2016-01-01' AND  DATE <= '2017-11-01'
            AND   CODE = 1111
         GROUP BY ID
       ) AS dT
```